# Asp.net Where to build viewmodels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building a mvc application from scratch. Currently i'm very in doubt where to put the mapping from domain entities to view models. I have the following project layout

- MVC application
- Bl Layer (per domain, so 1 for orders, 1 for customers etc)
- Repository layer. Per table mostly.

For example, now I need to build a grid. The controller is called to get the grid on the screen for example on the Index page. Then the index page calls the BL layer that eventually calls the repositories to access the data from the database. Now my question is, where should I map the domain enities to the viewmodels? I could do this in the controller or in the BL layer. What are the pro's and con's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep mapper logic at BL in seperate class not at controllers. Thats mainly because Its not the responsibilty of your controller to do the mapping. There should be another class to handle this mapping responsibilty. That's what [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle says, I think.

Better you have a look on some Object Oriented design [SOLID OOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) Principles.

Comment: Do you mean then in the controller call something like:

List<CityGridModel> cityGridModel = CityMapper.Map(cityService.GetCities()); Or would you do someting like List<CityGridModel cityGridModel = cityService.GetCities();

Comment: 2nd one is better i.e. `List<CityGridModel cityGridModel = cityService.GetCities();`, `GetCities()` will be at BL which will will call mapper to map it and then retun the final list.